# change string object to number in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a 880184*1 dataframe, the only column is either integer object or string object. I want to change all string object to number 0. It looks like below:

```
index               column
.....               ......
23155     WILLS ST / MIDDLE POINT RD
23156                          20323
23157    400 Block of BELLA VISTA WY
23158                          19090
23159     100 Block of SAN BENITO WY
23160                          20474
```

Now the problem is both number and string are 'object' type, I don't know how to change the string like object to 0 like below:

```
index                          column
.....                          ......
23155                            0
23156                          20323
23157                            0
23158                          19090
23159                            0
23160                          20474
```

Another problem is that the sample size is too large, making it too long to use for loops to fix row by row. I want to use something like:

```
df.loc[df.column == ...] = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is not a coding site where you can ask others to do work for you.  It is a Q/A site which strives to gather lots of questions more than one person could have and helpful answers to them.  You have to show your efforts, your non-working code and formulate a clear question on what you want us to answer.

Comment: Hi sorry, I don't mean to let others work for me. I am just stuck at this point and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the type to numeric with [`pd.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and pass `errors='coerce'` so that you would get `NaN` for the ones cannot be converted to numbers. In the end, you can replace the `NaN`s with zero:

```
df["column"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column"], errors="coerce").fillna(0)
Out[15]: 
0        0.0
1    20323.0
2        0.0
3    19090.0
4        0.0
5    20474.0
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

If you want the integer values, add `astype('int64')` to the end:

```
df["column"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column"], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype("int64")
Out[16]: 
0        0
1    20323
2        0
3    19090
4        0
5    20474
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

try converting everything to integers using the int() function.
The strings cannot be converted so an error is raised. Pack this in a "try" loop and you are set.

Like this:

```
def converter(currentRowObj):
    try:
        obj = int(currentRowObj)
    except:
        obj = 0
    return obj
```

Comment: [A bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341). Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like `except ValueError`, or at least `except Exception`.

Comment: How would you apply this to the df? `df['column'].apply(converter)`? In that case, `currentRowObj` isn't a row but a value, so I'd call it something else.